# How to replace the Python logo in a Tkinter-based Python GUI app?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Is there a way to change the default logo, which is the [Python logo](http://pytoexe.sourceforge.net/dosyalar/python_logo_without_textsvg.png), that appears in the Window's task bar?

Notice that I have already successfully replaced the default Tk logo that used to appear in my application window.

I am using Windows 7 and Python 2.6 and developing the GUI with the help of Tkinter.

Comment: Not within a Python program, no. You will either have to compile your program or change the Python logo in the settings of your Python installation- but this will be permanent until it is manually changed again in the same way.

Comment: do you mean `Tk().iconbitmap(default=logo.ico)`?

Comment: application bar or taskbar?

Comment: taskbar yes ! I am going to edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [winico](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tktable/files/winico/) Tk extension package. The winico package can also be used to add system tray icons to Tk programs.

The following sample shows one way to do change the runtime application icon. Note that you need to provide a .ico file with suitable sizes of icons in it on the command line and you need to use pythonw. It will not change the taskbar icon for the console when it is running python script. To test this I extracted the winico0.6 package into my `python\tcl\winico0.6` folder so the *package require Winico* would work and then ran the code below using `pythonw winico_test.py path\to\some\ico\file.ico`.

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

def main(argv):
    root = Tk()
    root.update()
    root.tk.call('package','require','Winico')
    id = root.tk.call('winico','createfrom',argv[1])
    root.tk.call('winico','setwindow',root,id,'big',0)
    root.mainloop()
    return 0

if __name__=='__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```